# show and hide divs based on path

Tags: url, html, directory, show

Thanks in advance. I've tried to piece this together based on numerous other posts and examples, but can't seem to make it work. What I'm after seems straightforward enough: show and hide particular divs depending on whether the page loaded is in a particular directory on the website. So, for example, I want 
the about-nav-on div to show anytime a file is in the /about directory on my site: www.mysite.com/about/about-us.html.

Below is my script, but it's not doing anything. The other divs, you might surmise, are the other menu items in my navigation, with -on being the ones that highlight the respective menu item. So in the example below, only the "off" divs show, the others are hidden, except in the last case, which is the one I want to highlight because this page is in the /about directory.

Again, thanks in advance. And be gentle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.pathname.split("/")[1] == 'about' ) {
        $('#nav-home').show();
        $('#nav-home-on').hide();
        $('#nav-believe').show();
        $('#nav-believe-on').hide();
        $('#nav-schedule').show();
        $('#nav-schedule-on').hide();
        $('#nav-directions').show();
        $('#nav-directions-on').hide();
        $('#nav-about').hide();
        $('#nav-about-on').show();
    }
});
```

Oh, and P.S.: I'll also need to have the nav-home-on div show for any page that lives in the root directory; so how will I parse that URL?

DD

Comment: Ah. Thanks, Erick; that looks better.

Answer (score 0):

After more research and tinkering, I discovered that the following works for the first part of my question, although I'm not sure exactly how this "if" statement sounds in plain English:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("believe") > -1) {
       $('#nav-home').show();
       $('#nav-home-on').hide();
       $('#nav-believe').hide();
       $('#nav-believe-on').show();
       $('#nav-schedule').show();
       $('#nav-schedule-on').hide();
       $('#nav-directions').show();
       $('#nav-directions-on').hide();
       $('#nav-about').show();
       $('#nav-about-on').hide();
    }
 });
```

Still, though, could use help with how to show/hide divs if the file I'm loading is in the root directory. For now, I'm just using:

```
        $(window).load(function(){  
        $('#nav-home').hide();
        $('#nav-home-on').show();
    }
```

in a script on the home page. But I'd like to find a way to do this in the .js file.